# js bootpag not loading pagination

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

My bootpag is not loading the pagination.I have spend several hour checking the rest of the code and it works good.The problem is that I'm unable to figure out why does not bootpag load.
Here is my code:

dashboard.php//Users dashboard

```
<?php
session_start();
......

......
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);
?>

<html>
<head>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_user.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#results").load("views/apps/get_apps_record.php");  //initial page number to load



 $(".paging_link").bootpag({
    total: <?php echo $pages; ?>
 }).on("page", function(e, num){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
  $("#results").load("views/apps/get_apps_record.php", {'page':num});
 });

});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Dashboard</title>

</head>

<body>

//loading the apps.php here

  ....
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
....
</body>
</html>
```

apps.php//the pagination is here

```
...

    <div id="results" class="list-group"></div>
    <div class="paging_link"></div>
....
```

In the #results the output is being loaded but the pagination is not showing up.
Any ideas?

Comment: you are including jquery twice..please remove one and it should work

Comment: removed the last one but still not loading

Comment: can you make js fiddle

Comment: i have lots of code and a database it would take me 1-2hours to strip it out

Answer (score 0):

Was missing:

```
  <script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
```

face palm!!!

Answer (score -1):

**I think you are misspelled.**

1. Please add your css files on head then
2. Add jquery ,then
3. Add bootstrap.min.js ,then
4. Add custom js scripts

Comment: same problem still

Comment: there is no need for the php part as i mentioned its working i can do it manually js is here the problem

Comment: Please remove jquery from the foot of your code.You already added it on top